# How do I check who's won the game?

Tags: java

I have a game which makes the players pick tokens from bags until the bags are empty, the last player to pick a token out of any of the bags wins.  But I'm not sure how I would check who wins.

**My code is basically:**

```
while (the game hasn't finished){
    Player 1 goes and then player 2 etc until the last token is drawn from the bag
}
```

**How would I go about checking who had the last go?**

Comment: Please post some actual code so we can see what you are working with and give a solution that best fits.

Comment: should i post the whole code?

Comment: while (bag1 != 0 || bag2 !=0 || bag3 != 0) {
   if (player1Turn = (player1Turn)?false:true){
    System.out.print("Player 2 - choose bag: " );
    while (!in.hasNextInt()){
     System.out.println("I said a bag between 1 and 3: ");
     in.nextLine();
    }
    bag = in.nextInt();
    if (bag == 1){

Comment: then checks if its bag 2 or 3. I did try this: if (bag1 != 0 || bag2 !=0 || bag3 != 0 || i%2 != 0){
    System.out.println("Game Over - Player 1 Wins");
   }else if (bag1 != 0 || bag2 !=0 || bag3 != 0 || i%2 == 0)
    System.out.println("Game Over - Player 2 Wins");
   },

Comment: Try using a boolean that gets set to true if it is player 1's turn and false if it is player 2's turn. Then use a if statement such as `if(someBool) Player 1 wins else Player 2 wins`

Comment: This is the code i came up with the boolean, but it doesn't work because player1Turn doesn't change i don't think: if (player1Turn = true){
    System.out.println("Game Over - Player 1 Wins");
   }else if (player1Turn = false)
    System.out.println("Game Over - Player 2 Wins");
   }

Answer (score 0):

Without some code, it's not really feasible to provide specific help. But what you'd want to do is add some logic into your main loop

```
currentPlayer = player1;
while (the game is not over) {
   currentPlayer draws;
   if (bag is empty) {
     currentPlayer wins;
     break;
   }
   if (currentPlayer is player1) { currentPlayer = player2; }
   else { currentPlayer = player1;
}
```